# Add javascript to Wordpress loop with class selection

Tags: javascript, wordpress, svg, snap.svg

I would like to add category icons to a Wordpress page, each icon animated with snap.svg.

- I added the div and inside an svg in the loop that prints the page (index.php). All divs are appearing with the right size of the svg, but blank.
- The svg has a class that is targeted by the js file.
- The js file is loaded and works fine by itself, but the animation appears only in the first div of that class, printed on each other as many times it is counted by the loop (how many posts there are on the actual page from that category).

I added "each()" and the beginning of the js, but is not allocating the animations on their proper places. I also tried to add double "each()" for the svg location and adding the snap object to svg too, but that was not working either.

I tried to add unique id to each svg with the post-id, but i could not pass the id from inside the loop to the js file. I went through many possible solutions I found here and else, but none were adaptable, because my php and js is too poor.

If you know how should I solve this, please answer me. Thank you!

// This is the js code (a little trimmed, because the path is long with many randoms, but everything else is there):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

jQuery(".d-icon").each(function() {

var dicon = Snap(".d-icon");

var dfirepath = dicon.path("M250 377 C"+ ......+ z").attr({ id: "dfirepath", class: "dfire", fill: "none", }); 

function animpath(){  dfirepath.animate({ 'd':"M250 377 C"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 271))+ .....+ z" }, 200, mina.linear);};

function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions, complete) { var x = 0; var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () { callback(); if (++x === repetitions) { window.clearInterval(intervalID);  complete();} }, delay); }

var dman = dicon.path("m136 ..... 0z").attr({ id: "dman", class:"dman", fill: "#222", transform: "r70",  }); 

var dslip = dicon.path("m307 ..... 0z").attr({ id: "dslip", class:"dslip", fill: "#196ff1", transform:"s0 0"});

var dani1 = function() { dslip.animate({ transform: "s1 1"}, 500, dani2); }
var dani2 = function() { dman.animate({ transform: 'r0  ' + dman.getBBox().cx + ' ' + dman.getBBox(0).cy, opacity:"1" }, 500, dani3 ); }
var dani3 = function() { dslip.animate({ transform: "s0 0"}, 300); dman.animate({ transform: "s0 0"}, 300, dani4); }
var dani4 = function() { dfirepath.animate({fill: "#d62a2a"}, 30, dani5); } 
var dani5 = function() { setIntervalX(animpath, 200, 10, dani6); }
var dani6 = function() { dfirepath.animate({fill: "#fff"}, 30); dman.animate({ transform: "s1 1"}, 100); } 

dani1();  });  });
```

Comment: Would help if you post the full JS snippet. Using a single `.each()` is the correct way to do it but probably you're doing something wrong down below the code.

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded the code, without the long path code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your error is here:

```
var dicon = Snap(".d-icon");
```

You are passing a query selector to the Snap constructor, this means Snap always tries to get the first DOM element with that class, hence why you're getting the animations at the wrong place.

You can either correct that in two ways:

1. Declare width and height inside the constructor, for example `var dicon = Snap(800, 600);`
2. Since you are using jQuery you can access to the current element inside `.each()` with the `$(this)` keyword. Since you are using `jQuery` instead of the dollar you could use `jQuery(this)`.

Please keep in mind this is a jQuery object and probably Snap will require a DOM object. In jQuery you can access the dom object by appending a `[0]` after the `this` keyword. If `var dicon = Snap( jQuery(this) );` does not work you can try with `var dicon = Snap( jQuery(this)[0] );`

Additionally, you have several `.attr({id : '...',`  in your code. I assume you are trying to associate to the paths an ID which are not unique. These should be relatively safe since they sit inside a SVG element and I don't see you are using those ID for future selection.

But if you have to select those at a later time I would suggest to append to these a numerical value so you wont have colliding ID names.

Comment: Wow, the "var dicon = Snap( jQuery(this)[0] );" actually worked. Many-many and a billion thanks to you. Your answer was quick, thorough and complete, and solved the problem in seconds. Thank you!